# Evaluate using Stokes' Theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

To evaluate $\oint_{C} -y^3dx+x^3dy+z^3dz,$ where $C$ is the intersection of cylinder $x^2 + y^2 =1$ and plane $x+y+z=1$. The orientation of $C$ is counter-clockwise motion in the $xy$ plane.

Now I have computed $\nabla \times\mathbf{F} = \left(0,0,3\left(x^2+y^2\right)\right).$ I am having difficulty finding out the curve $C$ of intersection and also I am confused about projection on the $xy$ plane. Should I take part inside $x+y=1 $ only or part between $x+y=1$ and $x^2+y^2=1?$

Comment: $C$ is definitely not in the $xy$ plane. It's the intersection between a cylinder and a plane that is not in the $xy$ plane. When the problem statement says that the orientation of $C$ is counter-clockwise motion in the $xy$ plane, it only means that if you were to look down at the $xy$ plane from a positive $z$ position, and watch $C$ get traversed, it would appear to be going counter-clockwise. Your $\nabla\times\mathbf{F}$ is correct.

Comment: Yes. But how to find out surface whose normal to be found out and projection on XY Plane

Comment: You don't need the projection onto the $xy$ plane at all, period. The surface $S$ in the expression $\displaystyle\iint_S\nabla\times\mathbf{F}\cdot dS$ is described by the intersection of $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x+y+z=1.$ I can tell you right now that the result of that intersection is an ellipse. Working...

Comment: The name is Stokes, not Stoke. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_George_Stokes,_1st_Baronet

Comment: The unit vector normal to the surface is $\hat{\mathbf{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1).$ But then you probably need the Jacobian to change $dS$ into appropriate differentials. Also, you'll need more information about the shape of the contained ellipse to get the right limits for the integrals.

Comment: Hang on: because of the nature of your particular $\nabla\times\mathbf{F},$ you actually might be able to go ahead with projecting everything onto the $xy$ plane; it is a fact that $(\nabla\times\mathbf{F})\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}=\sqrt{3}(x^2+y^2),$ and the only component that counts is in the $z$ direction.

Comment: how do you know surface of intersection is not cylinder but plane

Comment: To be clear: the intersection of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ with the plane $x+y+z=1$ is an ellipse. This is not a surface but a contour - the contour over which you're computing your original line integral. Stokes's Theorem says that if you're doing a simple, closed line integral, that's equivalent to a surface integral over the surface bounded by the contour. So it's incorrect to say "surface of intersection". The surface bounded by the intersection is an ellipse - the ellipse itself and everything in the $x+y+z=1$ plane bounded by that ellipse.

Comment: ok but surface is of no use to us. we need projection in xy plane to compute using stokes.

Comment: You don't *need* the projection, you can parametrize the surface in terms of variables that are not $x$ and $y$, but $x$ and $y$ are indeed convenient here. If $\mathcal S$ is the interior of the ellipse in the $x + y + z = 1$ plane (and you're also free to take some other, non-planar, surface bounded by the ellipse), then
$$d \mathbf S = \nabla(x + y + z) \, dx dy,\\
\iint_{\mathcal S} (\nabla \times \mathbf F) \cdot d\mathbf S =
\iint_{x^2 + y^2 < 1} (3 x^2 + 3 y^2) \, dx dy.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{F}=\left(-y^3,x^3,z^3\right).$
So we have
\begin{align*}
\oint_{C} -y^3dx+x^3dy+z^3dz&=\oint_C\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r} \\
&=\iint_S(\nabla\times\mathbf{F})\cdot dS \\
&=\iint_S(\nabla\times\mathbf{F})\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}\,dA \\
&=\sqrt{3}\iint_S\left(x^2+y^2\right)\,dA.
\end{align*}
My hunch is that we can consider the projection into the $xy$ plane of the surface $S$ for this problem, because the integrand $\nabla\times\mathbf{F}$ only has a $z$ component. If that is so, we will want to switch to polar coordinates:
\begin{align*}
\oint&=\sqrt{3}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\left(x^2+y^2\right)\,r\,dr\,d\theta \\
&=2\sqrt{3}\,\pi\int_0^1 r^3\,dr \\
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\pi}{2}.
\end{align*}
As we can see from [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projected_area), to adjust for the projection, we need
$$A_{\text{proj}}=\cos(\beta) A, $$
since the angle is constant and pulls out of the integral. We have computed the projected area, so we must compensate by dividing by $\cos(\beta),$ we can calculate via the dot product formula:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)\cdot(0,0,1)=\cos(\beta). $$ 
This means the final result is
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\pi}{2}\div\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{3\pi}{2}. $$

Now the question is, was the projection justified? Can we verify by, say, computing the original line integral? As suggested by DiegoMath in his answer, we can parametrize the curve $C$ as 
\begin{align*}
x&=\cos(t) \\
y&=\sin(t) \\
z&=1-\cos(t)-\sin(t),\\
0&\le t\le 2\pi.
\end{align*}
Then we have 
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{r}(t)&=(\cos(t), \sin(t), 1-\cos(t)-\sin(t))\\
\dot{\mathbf{r}}(t)&=(-\sin(t), \cos(t), \sin(t)-\cos(t)) \\
\mathbf{F}(t)&=(-\sin^3(t),\cos^3(t),(1-\cos(t)-\sin(t))^3) \\
\mathbf{F}\cdot\dot{\mathbf{r}}&=\sin^4(t)+\cos^4(t)+(\sin(t)-\cos(t))(1-\cos(t)-\sin(t))^3 \\
\oint_C\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}&=\oint_C\mathbf{F}\cdot \dot{\mathbf{r}}(t)\,dt \\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\left[\sin^4(t)+\cos^4(t)+(\sin(t)-\cos(t))(1-\cos(t)-\sin(t))^3\right]dt \\
&=\frac{3\pi}{2},
\end{align*}
which is the answer we had above.

Comment: why answer don't match

Comment: Just figured it out. See edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. btw how do you know limits of t are from 0 to 2 $\pi$

Comment: Because of the way we parametrized the curve: we have to get all the way around the curve exactly once.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Since $x^2+y^2=1$ you have that
$$x=\cos t\quad y=\sin t\quad 0\leq t\leq2\pi.$$
Thus, a parametrization for the curve $C$ is

$$x=\cos t\quad y=\sin t\quad z=1-\cos t-\sin t\quad 0\leq t\leq2\pi.$$

Comment: Doesn't the OP want to switch to a surface integral via Stokes's Theorem?